# Maximizing the p-value associated with a goodness-of-fit test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, anderson-darling-test

**Problem (concrete version)**: Let $p = p(T, \mathcal{D}, \mathbf{X})$ be the $p$-value associated with goodness-of-fit test $T$ (i.e. Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Anderson-Darling, Cramér–von Mises) on distribution $\mathcal{D}$ (i.e. normal, beta, gamma) with sample points $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, \cdots, X_n)$. Suppose we know $T, \mathcal{D}$ and $n$ is fixed. Is there a way to solve
\begin{align*}
\underset{\mathbf{X}}{\text{argmax}} \quad p(T, \mathcal{D}, \mathbf{X})
\end{align*}
**Problem (more abstractly):** Given a distribution $\mathcal{D}$, how can I select $n$ points which is "most representative" of that distribution? The problem I am working on requires *selecting* points from such distribution, but not *sampling* points. That is, we cannot have these points differ between experiments, hence why we would like to get the most representative points the first time around. In terms of something more concrete, I defined representativeness as the $p$-value associated with a goodness-of-fit test, but I'm certainly open to other ideas, especially one with a simple analytical solution.

**Examples**: Let $T = $ Kolmogorov-Smirnov and $\mathcal{D} = \text{Unif}(0, 1)$. For $n = 1, 2, 3$, we may calculuate in R:

```
> x = c(0.5)
> ks.test(x, "punif")

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.5, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

> x = c(0.25, 0.75)
> ks.test(x, "punif")

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.25, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

> x = c(1/6, 0.5, 5/6)
> ks.test(x, "punif")

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.16667, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Of course, this is a relatively easy example where I could guess the maximum arguments. But more generally, this is not the case. We could perform a grid-search, but the dimension of this grid-search grows with $n$, and it's complicated further if $\mathcal{D}$ itself is a multivariate distribution.

Thanks!